# Excel filtering / hiding columns using dynamic macros

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have a spreadsheet that is incredibly large hundreds of columns by thousands or rows, I have the ability to check boxes to determine what columns are displayed. The problem is I now want to group the columns based on the value of a cell towards the top of each column (Row 10). This would allow the category to be dynamic and will allow an item to change from one category to another and be either hidden or displayed based on the check box state for that category.

The code that I currently have in the macro to allow the checkbox to toggle between hidden and visible per each team is below. they are currently grouped in groups of 20, I want to eliminate the static grouping of 20 and replace that with the array of columns whose cell on row 10 contains the category (Currently "Team 1" in this example.

```
Sub Team1()
Set target = Range("B1")
If target.Value = "TRUE" Or target.Value = "True" Then
    ActiveSheet.Columns("F:Y").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
ElseIf target.Value = "FALSE" Or target.Value = "False" Then
    ActiveSheet.Columns("F:Y").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `For` Loop to check each Columns Row 10 value, then set the `.hidden` property of the `entireColumn` accordingly:

```
Sub Team1()
    Dim target As Range
    Dim checkCell As Range

    Set target = Range("B1")

    For Each checkCell In Range("F10:Y10").Cells
        checkCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = (LCase(target.Value) = "true" And checkCell.Value = "Team 1")
    Next checkCell

End Sub
```

The `For Each` loop will loop through each `cell` in the `range` `F10:Y10`.

There's no need for `IF... Then` here since `.Hidden` has a `true/false` assignment. The `(LCase(target.Value) = "true" And checkCell.Value = "Team 1")` bit will either return `True` or `False` depending on those two conditions.

Comment: That does not work properly since I have multiple different Teams, your example works for toggling one and only one on and off but will now work when combined with 2 or more teams. I may have not explained it clearly enough in the initial post but say there are 10 teams I want to be able to select for example teams 3,5,8 and view only those 3. That was the reason for the if else statements.